# Teaching Kids to Debug Code?

Tags: debugging, lua

So there are a lot of posts around here about what are the best ways to teach kids to program. I'm interested in the next step, teaching kids how to debug code that doesn't do what they want, or doesn't always work 100% of the time (I believe these are separate problems, but that could be subjective).

I ask from the point of view of a game developer who already has a working game (ROBLOX) where kids can code up a ton of crazy stuff in our embedded scripting language, which happens to be Lua.

What we are seeing is that as these scripts become more complicated they are suffering from edge cases that the kids didn't consider - ultimately limiting the scope of what they can do. Part of the solution is education and part of the solution is better debugging tools. Thus I ask a two part question:

1. What high quality, freely available sources of information exist on the internet that we can send aspiring script developers to with any expectation that they would get something valuable out of it? Maybe there aren't any and we need to write some?
2. What debugging tools do you think would be most useful to kids? I want to hit the payoff vs. complexity sweet spot.

Our target demographic here is motivated kids, mostly 12-15 years old.

Comment: Why limit this to kids though?  Learning to debug is part art, part skill, part ability - but getting to be acceptable/good/better/great at it would be something that almost all of us would be interested in.

Comment: There are currently a small number of questions here tagged Lua that are about ROBLOX. One side thing for your organization to try might be to task someone to monitor the Lua (and roblox?) tag to provide "expert" answers to questions. The rest of us know a lot of Lua, but lack the game context to help the more game-focused questions. The same suggestion would apply to WoW, of course.

Comment: We tried to set up our own ROBLOX Overflow through Area51, but the launch rules all but guaranteed we wouldn't be successful since all of our users are new to SO and have 0 rep. Since then, some ROBLOX community members have built homegrown solutions, so I imagine it's less of an issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for the debugging part, my guess would be three things:

- Avoid bugs in the first place by teaching them [good programming practice](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide)
- Test each part with eg. unit-testing ([Lunit](http://www.nessie.de/mroth/lunit/))
- use `print()` enough for seeing what happens
- you might be interested in [debugger.lua](https://github.com/norman/lua-devtools/blob/master/debugger.lua) or [Remdebug](http://www.keplerproject.org/remdebug)
- Use a decent editor with syntax highlighting, bracket matching, ...

For the general information:

- [Learning Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LearningLua) on the Lua-users wiki
- [The Lua reference manual](http://lua.org/manual/5.1/)
- [Programming in Lua](http://lua.org/pil/)

That's the way I learned using Lua anyway :).

Comment: bearing in mind that you can't control 1 at all with legacy code.

Answer (score 8):

IMHO: Never mind tools. Talk them through it. Teach problem-solving skills. And just as importantly, teach **testing**.

Comment: Have you ever seen this done well within the context of a game?

Comment: Not that I can recall, but that doesn't make it the wrong thing to do/attempt. :)

Comment: Its possible that a game could be a really good way to teach it. Some sort of series of challenges that are solved through debugging-like behaviors, perhaps. Teach them to debug when they aren't looking.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, early start always helps. In the early years, brains aren’t wired to one particular language like in adulthood. http://blog.quib.ly/2012/10/30/can-kids-beat-adults-at-coding/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the "sources of information" part. It looks a bit too generic to me. I learned about edge cases with painful experience, and don't know any other means. I'm not sure it is a kind of knowledge that can be taught formally. It's more like an intuitive thing to me. Kind of like swimming: in order to learn, you have to get wet.

But regarding payoff-vs-complexity part, I'd say that nothing beats the good old console + print duet. It might not be as fancy as other debugging means, but its complexity asymptotically approaches 0. And it's something they will be able to use in nearly any environment and any language they encounter in the future (unless something really big happens).

Answer (score 1):

If you have iPad, now there's a nice app that lets you write programs/games/simulations and run it directly from your iPad. The language is Lua.

http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/

Answer (score 0):

I would use Netbeans after stripping it down a bit.  It has some very nice code hinting and comprehensible error checking and hinting.

Comment: I know there is a project working on Lua integration with Eclipse. I haven't heard about one for Netbeans. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Kids can have restricted access to tools like debuggers as an individual may not be registered as a programmer or (game) software developer in the state or at the national level. Lua can be run in debug or trace mode and there is something to be gained by reading through the program script or code and using a pen and paper with test input values to note the variables and their contents with logic jumps separately noted with any return expectation and assess the output data values created at relevant points. This is sometimes called dryrunning and is used normally prior to first full test in the development process. This can help in coping with sometimes complex logic progress and with stack element contents written from bottom to top or from left to right on the paper.